# What does volume means at the quantum level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, volume

> *The volume of the electron is the space bounds in which it is contained*

says the @CuriousOne. But how can we define the volume in such a small range.

If we immerse a cuboid into a vessel full of water, then we can define its volume as the volume raised in the vessel.

Can you give an analogy to electron? Or any other better definition?

Comment: Did you mean the volume of the particle itself?

Comment: @Richardbernstein Yes, the volume of the particle

Answer (score 2):

The "volume in which it is contained" is an ill-defined notion for quantum objects.

Consider the simplest atom, the hydrogen atom, and look at the [wavefunctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Wavefunction) for the electron states. You find that, roughly,

$$ \psi(r) \propto \mathrm{e}^{-r}$$

so the probability to find an electron at a certain distance $r$ from the nucleus decreases with increasing distance, but *never* reaches *quite* zero.

The electron does not really occupy a "volume" as this shows, and neither does any other quantum object. We usually are satisfied with saying that a quantum object *occupies* a volume if the probability to find it outside it is "neglegible" - where how small it has to be to be neglegible depends on what you are looking for: For example, you might say that the nucleons of atoms are confined to the, well, nucleus, since you almost never find one of them outside - except for when you do, and that's called [$\alpha$-decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_decay).

Comment: That's not even correct for a hydrogen atom because the weighted wave function does occupy a finite volume, and it's certainly not correct for a soup can, which is a model for a contained space with (essentially) infinite walls. The chances of measuring a particle caught on the inside on the outside are nil during any imaginable lifetime of the universe. That some people get caught in "but it could happen in infinite time" is understandable, but it's not a physical way of looking at reality.

Comment: @CuriousOne: What is this *weighted wavefunction*? And yes, if the potential walls are essentially "infinite", then the particle will be trapped inside them. Yet, again, what you call "infinite" depends on what you are looking for - I think the nucleus/$\alpha$-decay example illustrates this nicely.

Comment: The electron in a hydrogen atom simply "doesn't care" about what happens far away from the proton. The probability of finding a ground state electron more than 100 (or so) times farther away from the proton than its average distance is zero during the lifetime of the universe. If something doesn't happen in reality, there is no point in making it a center of a scientific consideration, hence a naive volume calculation is pointless for physical purposes.

Comment: Well @ACuriousMind you are speaking about the volume with which it is contained. Yah, surely it's described by the probability wave function. But the volume which a small particle occupies is not explained by probability wave function. And my question is volume definable to quantum particles

Comment: @AfrishKhan: Quantum objects are not classical particles, all they are is described by their state/wavefunction.

Comment: I guess the particles position only is given by probability wave function

Answer (score 0):

When a cuboid is immersed in water, the molecules at each face of the cube repels the water molecules making the cuboid having a definite boundary and that causes it to have a definite volume. But, how do this analogy works with an electron?
     Hence, the volume at quantum level is indefinable.